# Dump debug steps in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging

Is it possible to dump the entire program **steps** to a file? I don't mean the value of the variables, I mean the jumping from on instruction to another, and if it's possible to use both, steps and the var values

I've used both gdb and GUI(ddd), and I use the regular step all the time but sometimes I have a loop and network application so I don't want to affect the flaw of the program, I just want to see what happened exactly after everything is done.

For instance,

```
1 #include<stdio.h>
2 
3 int main()
4 {
5
6 int i = 0, y = 0;
7
8 for (y; y< 10; y++) {
9    i++;    
10    printf("%d\n", i)
11 }
12 return 0;
13
14 }
```

So the dump file will contain all the steps from int main() to return 0, like below for example

```
1. on 1
2. on 2
...
...
8. on 8
9. on 9
10. on 10
11. on 8
12. on 9
... and so on until the loop finishes and then hit return and exit.
```

Comment: It is in principle possible with recent GDB (7.6 was released a few days ago) and GCC (4.8 was released a few weeks ago), because GDB can be configured to be scriptable in Python. Coding the python script to do that is left as an exercise (which I don't know how to do).

Comment: that's a typo :), it was i = i+1 then I decided to use i++

Comment: `OllyDbg` has the `animate` and `trace` features, which seem to be close to what you want, but it is Windows only and an assembly level debugger.
However searching for these keywords could bring you on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Using GDB you could use [process record and replay](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord). Another option is [Jockey](http://home.gna.org/jockey/) which functions as a record/replay preload library.